# Give User Create and Update View Permissions only

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know if there is a way in MySQL to allow the user to create / alter views without giving the user the ability to drop table within the database?

I have the need to give user ability to create / alter views.

Don't know if you can deny drop permissions to specific table and would that still effect the ability of the user to create / update views.

The reason I am asking this is because I am not the DBA of the system, but need to be able to create views.

Again, if someone can tell me it is or isn't possible, or even shed some light on how it can be done.

Comment: How about having a look in the manual? Look up "grant privileges".

Answer (score 0):

Taken directly from the manual:

From the page about the [DROP privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_drop):

> The DROP privilege enables you to drop (remove) existing databases, tables, and views. The DROP privilege is required in order to use the statement ALTER TABLE ... DROP PARTITION on a partitioned table. The DROP privilege is also required for `TRUNCATE TABLE`. If you grant the DROP privilege for the mysql database to a user, that user can drop the database in which the MySQL access privileges are stored.

And from the page about [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html):

> To use ALTER TABLE, you need ALTER, CREATE, and INSERT privileges for the table. Renaming a table requires ALTER and DROP on the old table, ALTER, CREATE, and INSERT on the new table.

So the answer to your question is: no.  You cannot deny DROP privileges for a specific table and DROP is required in order to use `ALTER TABLE`.